# How to show that $\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2]$ is the smallest subfield of $\mathbb R$ containing $\mathbb Q$ and $\sqrt 2?$

Tags: field-theory

How to show that $\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2]=\{a+b\sqrt 2:a,b\in\mathbb Q\}$ is the smallest subfield of $\mathbb R$ containing $\mathbb Q$ and $\sqrt 2?$

I've shown that $\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2]$ is a subfield of $\mathbb R.$ What about the *smallest* case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it clear to you what *smallest* means in this context? This kind of statement means that any other subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ containing $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\sqrt2$ contains $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt2]$. Can you show this? (It's fairly obvious and certainly the easier containment of the two to show...).

Comment: Oh yes! BTW then any subring of $\mathbb R$ containning $\mathbb Q$ and $\sqrt 2$ contains $\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2].$ Isn't it?

Comment: It is actually the smallest subring containing $\mathbb Q$ and $\sqrt 2?$

Comment: It is, yes, but be careful; in general a subring of a field isn't necessarily a field.

Comment: Such as $\mathbb Z[\sqrt 2]$ of $\mathbb R.$ right?

Comment: That is one such example, yes!